# How to select child of label where there is no current selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can select (in JavaScript) a specific label where the labels are generated from a database and don't have a unique identifier.

The selector of the label is: `#content1 > div:nth-child(2) > label`. I have tried the following but getting an error

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

```
$("#content1 > div:nth-child(2) > label").click(function(){
    $( "#bestdeals1 > div:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "greenbestdeals" );
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the number 2? If you are getting that number from somewhere, and it is not a number, that would result in your observed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the function it self.

Changing the behavior to : `$(document).on("click", "#content1 > div:nth-child(2) > label", function(evt) {}`

Made it work. Thanks for the answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

In case you weren't already using it that way, nth-child starts at 1 and not 0, which could be causing the error.

You can also use jQuery functions to find the children, like this:

```
$('#content1').find('div').eq(1).children('label').first()
```

You can replace find with children assuming what you're going for is an immediate descendant - find will go however many levels deep it needs to until it finds the target.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
$('#content > div').eq(2).find('label').click(function() {
    // ...
});
```